page count on a kiosk that is html based?
I am doing some update work for a local museum to a kiosk I developed 13 years ago.  They would like to get an idea of how many people are using the kiosk and asked if I could put a page counter on the site. Of course I could go out and get a web counter and add it to the pages of the site on but I'm wondering, since the code resides on the kiosk already is there a way of getting stats off the computer now?
We moved the kiosk software to a Windows 11 based machine.  I can task the museum with some work to look for the numbers but they're not a techie group and I can't ask them use a complicated workflow.
Currently there isn't a budget for redesign, that's part of what the page counter is for.  The original hardware finally died and we are just working on getting the kiosk running on modern hardware so I'm trying to keep my hours low.  This is one of the last projects I did working with html and I've forgotten much of what I knew since getting into a new career.
I've done a couple google searches without finding a solution but since I've entered a new field I'm not sure what's been happening with this technology and thought it would be easier to ask those of you who know what you're doing for answers.

eh, well, you need somewhere to store this data, then you can update and retrieve it as often as you like. If your backend is only capable of serving html, and isn't capable of storing data, then you're kinda limited at what you can do.

Kevin, that's not really answering what I'm trying to ask.  I'm hosting a website on a Windows 11 system that is running in Kiosk mode for visitors of a museum.  Does the fact that I'm hosting the site on the same system that's running the Kiosk mean I can get any stats from it?  I can add a page counter to the pages of the site easily enough, but don't want to take the time because we may be tossing the site and doing a complete re-do of it.

No, the browser can't interact with the local machine unless it's running a webserver. aka, somewhere to store the data.

you could store information in the current window's cookies or localstorage, however that will be limited to that single machine and will reset in certain common conditions (such as restarting the pc or the browser or after a time period)

Thanks Kevin, that clears it up for me.  Probably easiest just to add some counters.
